# Swing : font color & strike color in JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, fonts, jtextpane

I have a JTextPane in which text color is set as blue by default. Now i added strike-through on text then strike-through color becomes as same of text (blue).  I want the color of text and strike-through different. e.g. if text color is blue then the strike-through must be different.

Please give me some idea.

```
    JTextPane text = new JTextPane();

    Font font = new Font("Serif", Font.ITALIC, 20);
    text.setFont(font); 

    text.setForeground(Color.BLUE); 

    Style style = text.addStyle("Bold", null);
    StyleConstants.setStrikeThrough(style, true);

    text.setCharacterAttributes(style, false);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class Test {

    public Test() {
        JFrame fr = new JFrame("TEST");
        fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JEditorPane pane = new JEditorPane();
        pane.setEditorKit(new NewEditorKit());
        pane.setText("test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test ");

        StyledDocument doc = (StyledDocument) pane.getDocument();
        MutableAttributeSet attr = new SimpleAttributeSet();
        attr.addAttribute("strike-color", Color.red);
        doc.setCharacterAttributes(0, 9, attr, false);

        attr.addAttribute("strike-color", Color.blue);
        doc.setCharacterAttributes(10, 19, attr, false);
        JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(pane);

        fr.getContentPane().add(sp);
        fr.setSize(300, 300);
        fr.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        fr.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
    }
}

class NewEditorKit extends StyledEditorKit {
    public ViewFactory getViewFactory() {
        return new NewViewFactory();
    }
}

class NewViewFactory implements ViewFactory {
    public View create(Element elem) {
        String kind = elem.getName();
        if (kind != null) {
            if (kind.equals(AbstractDocument.ContentElementName)) {
                return new MyLabelView(elem);
            }
            else if (kind.equals(AbstractDocument.ParagraphElementName)) {
                return new ParagraphView(elem);
            }
            else if (kind.equals(AbstractDocument.SectionElementName)) {
                return new BoxView(elem, View.Y_AXIS);
            }
            else if (kind.equals(StyleConstants.ComponentElementName)) {
                return new ComponentView(elem);
            }
            else if (kind.equals(StyleConstants.IconElementName)) {
                return new IconView(elem);
            }
        }

        // default to text display
        return new LabelView(elem);
    }
}

class MyLabelView extends LabelView {

    public MyLabelView(Element elem) {
        super(elem);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g, Shape allocation) {
        super.paint(g, allocation);
        paintStrikeLine(g, allocation);
    }

    public void paintStrikeLine(Graphics g, Shape a) {
        Color c=(Color)getElement().getAttributes().getAttribute("strike-color");
        if (c!=null) {
            int y = a.getBounds().y + a.getBounds().height - (int) getGlyphPainter().getDescent(this);
            y = y - (int) (getGlyphPainter().getAscent(this) * 0.3f);
            int x1 = (int) a.getBounds().getX();
            int x2 = (int) (a.getBounds().getX() + a.getBounds().getWidth());

            Color old = g.getColor();
            g.setColor(c);
            g.drawLine(x1, y, x2, y);
            g.setColor(old);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi StanislavL, This example using the static value which is already set in coding. I want to apply strike-through on input text instead of hard-coding text.

Comment: You can define a constant for the attribute name.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do the trick...

```
MutableAttributeSet attributes = text.getInputAttributes();
StyleConstants.setStrikeThrough(attributes , true);
StyleConstants.setForeground(attributes , Color.BLack);

StyledDocument doc = text.getStyledDocument();
doc.setCharacterAttributes(0, doc.getLength() + 1, attributes, false);
```

Comment: Hi Velter, I tried it before and it doesn't make any changes.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could have a look at StyledLabels:

http://www.jidesoft.com/products/JIDE_Common_Layer_Developer_Guide.pdf

At page 15...